# What is Windows doing when it's "Calculating..." after it finishes moving/copying files and sits at 99% done for 3-30 seconds?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

Something I've observed lately on Windows 10 for the past couple of years, *especially* when working with cross-drive and NAS/SMB shares:

1. Move or copy a few hundred files around between two drives on a local computer, or between folders *within the same SMB share*.

   - I know moving files isn't the same as a copy, but the long pause at the end still happens.
2. Notice the copy progress dialog will advance as usual...
3. ...but then it will then sit at 99% for a while: sometimes just a few seconds, but sometimes as long as 30 seconds or longer - with it waiting for longer when the number of files was large, especially when it spans multiple directories.

   - The "Name:" field shows the last directory moved/copied.
   - The "Time remaining:" field will display "0 seconds" right before it gets stuck, then it just says "Calculating...".
   - The "Items remaining:" field will display "0 (0 bytes)", indicating that it *did* finish the copying, right?
4. So *what is it doing* when it's "Calculating..." at 99% at the end?

[image]

---

- I disabled my anti-virus and other programs that could affect disk IO and network IO.
- I monitored what my computer with ProcMon when it was doing this and noticed that `explorer.exe` seems to spend a lot of time reading through `AutomaticDestinations` when it's "Calculating...", though I don't know why, or if this is even a cause of the delay or not.

[image]

Comment: Explorer is well-known as being the slowest file-copier on Earth. There is no point in trying to reverse-engineer its awful algorithms. See [link](https://superuser.com/questions/135277/how-to-skip-calculating-time-when-copying-files-using-windows-explorer).